# New Relic @Trace vs. Segment in Java

Tags: java, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I've tried looking this up, but I haven't found any adequate answer.

Whats the difference between annotating a method with `@Trace` and wrapping the contents of the method with `NewRelic.getAgent().getTransaction().startSegment()` and `segment.end()`?

What about nested `@Traces` and nested `Segments`?

If `method1` calls `method2` and both have `@Trace`/`Segment`, and `method1` takes totally 100ms out which `method2` takes 70 ms.

How will it be reported? `method1` is 100ms or 30 ms?

Finally, what if the two are mixed?

Answer (score 1):

Nested traces are possible and very useful. If you only annotate the controller, you have no control over the nested methods being called.

The method annotated with @Trace(dispatcher = true), will show up as 'parent' while nested annotations are aggregated under this parent in the NewRelic dashboard.

In your example, method 1 will show up as 100ms.

You can find more information about @Trace and Segmentation on: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/transactions/transaction-traces/transaction-trace-details

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought so too but I noticed in New Relic (where I have a similar setup) that the wrapper method (method1) is showing as less time than the method2. Also any idea what could be the difference between the two?